# How to specify the type of http request in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am writting a view named index. I want to specify that it can handle not only get requests but also post. In flask it was done by decorator, how to achieve it using django? I use Django 1.9.5

Comment: Is it a class or function based view? Function based views will accept all request types without having to specify anything. Class based views are slightly different but generally you add a method named the same as the request type (e.g. `get` for GET requests, `post` for POST requests, etc)

Comment: You can use the `allowed_methods` decorator to __limit__ a function based view to only accept certain methods https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods